# CKEditor 4 gives CKEDITOR not defined in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ckeditor-component package to integrate ckeditor in my react app. This component provides props for custom ckeditor scripts. It works fine with default script. it works fine when I use cnd script.
**Problem**.
it does not works when I try to use my custom build script url. It gives CKEDITOR is not defined error in console. here is how I am using.

```
enter code here
<CKEditor
    activeClass="p10"
    scriptUrl={require('assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}
    content={this.state.footerContent}
    events={{
           "change": this.onFooterChange
    }}
/>
```

Comment: What is your "custom build script url"? How do you use it?

Comment: It is the build that you download from ckeditor website. https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/. It is same as this cdn "cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.0/standard/ckeditor.js" the only diffrence is this is standard build and that one is custom build that reside inside my project locally

Comment: May be it is silly to ask but have you verified your path?? try putting that path in browser and check?